# How can I use mongoose in node js?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am beginner level in Node JS and here I am trying to connect to MongoDB.

I am following one tutorial and based on that, I have following project structure:

```
- server
  - config
    - db.js
  - index.js
- index.js
```

My mongoose dependency version is: 5.6.9

Inside my db.js, I have following code of lines:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// connection to mongoose
export default () => {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbCollection', function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the server. Please start the server. Error:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Connected to Server successfully!');
        }
    });
}
```

And inside the index.js inside the server folder, I have

```
import express from 'express';
import dbConfig from './config/db';

const app = express();
dbConfig();
```

But I am getting error

```
 _mongoose2.default.connection().once('open', function () {
                       ^

TypeError: _mongoose2.default.connection is not a function
    at exports.default
```

Comment: You are using ES6 syntax which is not yet supported by NodeJs by default, so you have 2 options : 1/ In Node9 you can enable Es6 support using `node --experimental-modules index.mjs` [Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html). 2/ Use Es5 syntax : `module.exports = () => {...}` and `const dbConfig = require('./config/db');`

Comment: @MoadEnnagi which one is better?

Comment: If you are a beginner I recommend you rewrite it to ES5.

Comment: @nas ES6 support is Experimental in Node9.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connect = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/dbCollection");

connect.then((db) => {
    console.log('Connected correctly to server');
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
    // next(err)
});
```

Comment: (0, _db2.default)();
                 ^

TypeError: (0 , _db2.default) is not a function i stil have this err

Answer (score 0):

**Database Connection And  listen Port**

```
// import dependencies
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import logger from 'morgan';// set up dependencies
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.use(logger('dev'));// set up mongoose

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/projectsupport')
  .then(()=> {
    console.log('Database connected');
  })
  .catch((error)=> {
    console.log('Error connecting to database');
  });

// set up port
    const port = 5035;// set up route
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Welcome to Project Support',
      });
    });app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Our server is running on port ${port}`);
    });
```